# Null-coalescing operators with operands of different types

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I understand that you cannot have different types compounding into one result, but I don't understand *why* this is.

Eg.

```csharp
Guid? ID;
int ID2;
var ID3 = ID ?? ID2;
```

The above code does not work, regardless of the nullability of `ID` or the type of `ID3`, var, object etc.

Can anyone explain why this isn't allowed?

My actual code looks like this:

```csharp
public StandAloneMachine Get(int id, Guid? FKGuid = null, string FKName = "") 
{ 
    var parameters = new Parameters() 
    { 
        new Parameter("id", FKGuid ?? id) 
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205973/discussion-on-question-by-ruanne-bornman-null-coalescing-operators-with-differen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone have a reason why this isn't allowed?

This is how the language is designed. What should it do? How'd you convert an `int`, which is a 32-bit number, into a `GUID`, which is a structure composed of several number portions, or vice-versa?

This code:

```
var ID3 = ID ?? ID2
```

translated into types means (*pseudocode*):

```
(inferred type_) = Guid? ?? int;
```

and the `??` operator naturally requires the types of its arguments to be compatible. The actual rules are fairly complex and can be found [in the C# language specification here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-null-coalescing-operator).

Anyway, the null-coalescing operator returns a single value and both its left and right arguments must be evaluated into a value of the same type. Hence, the result could be *either* a `Guid`, *or* an `int`. The `(inferred type)` would then be this type. However, the `??` cannot convert the values of `Guid` and `int` operands into a value of such a single type.

Note: You could argue that the compiler could choose `object` as the closes type compatible with both `Guid` and `int` and just box those values into an object. However, that would undermine the very sense of strong type checking. It would be just 'too relaxed'.

In your particular example, sticking with `??` seems artificial; a good old `?:` and a little bit more expressiveness in your code would do better and maybe even help readability:

```
var parameters = new Parameters() 
{ 
    new Parameter("id", FKGuid.HasValue ? ToTypeParameterExpects(FKGuid.Value) : ToTypeParameterExpects(id)) 
};
```

Obviously, the `ToTypeParameterExpects` is a conversion to whatever type the `Parameter`'s constructor expects for the value.

Comment: _This is how the language is designed_
This seems to be the truth looking at the specification you and Amy linked

Thank you for the update with regards to the note